# A laser shooting dragon?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, creature-design, dragons

This dragon uses very intense bursts of EM radiation as its “breath” attack. Obviously it can’t breathe light, but the attack originates from its mouth. This beam of light can permanently blind unshielded eyes and is hot enough to burn skin and ignite dry materials such as wood. In addition, the entire dragon is bioluminescent, and can blind attackers by raising its scales and releasing bright flashes of light. Finally, it is armed with a venom that reacts with the blood to produce a bright glow, allowing the dragon to track its prey in any weather or even total darkness.

The question here is: **how could an organism generate and direct large amounts of electromagnetic radiation without using any type of technology?**

Preferably, I would like the majority of the radiation to be between infrared and ultraviolet waves, but if other waves are easier to generate I’m ok with that too. I would like this answer to have as little handwavium as possible, and there is no magic in the setting. However, if this isn’t possible as far as our current understanding of biology and physics goes, then I’m willing to accept the most plausible sounding answer.

Comment: having the venom glow likely won't actually help with tracking particularly well as the prey would still have to be in eye sight to have any effect, all this would do is reduce camouflage. Realistically you'd be better off having the same sort of tracking compounds vipers use on their victims to follow their scent.

Comment: The page Samuel mentioned would probably answer your question.

Comment: Too short for an answer: Piezoelectric teeth.

Comment: Can I just say that it was with great joy that I read DUPLICATE on a question about a laser shooting dragon...I love this community. I love that this has been asked before, even if the word dragon wasn't used!